# iterative count

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I have a table of people which contains a unique ID for each person. Another table also contains their unique ID and the number of purchases they have at some store. How can I count the number of purchases they have?

```
SELECT 
    PERSON.ID, 
    PERSON.NAME, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE PERSON.ID = PURCHASE.PERSON_ID) AS 'Total Purchases'
FROM PERSON_TABLE AS PERSON, PURCHASE_TABLE AS PURCHASE
```

This example current command just counts the number of purchases there are total. How do I do the count per person?

Comment: Learn to use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 25 years.

Comment: @Eric could you explain how to use it in my specific case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use aggregation:

```
select pe.id, pe.name, count(pu.person_id) total_purchases
from person_table pe
left join purchase_table pu on pu.person_id = p.id
group by pe.id, pe.name
```

This gives you the count of records in `purchase_table` for each row in `person_table`; the `left join` is there to handle persons that have no purchase at all, in which case `count(pu.person_id)` would yield `0`.

Comment: I noticed a "left join"; could you explain how this command works?

Comment: is it possible to do internal operations on that join? Say I want to find all the purchases with a total than $20, (`PURCHASE_TABLE.TOTAL`) how do I go about that?